# Transforming .osm file into a .svg file with an equivalent geometry, without applying styling

Tags: openstreetmap, convert, svg

I have an existing `.osm` file (containing a small part of OpenStreetMap database). I am looking for way to convert it into `.svg` file.

Note that I am not interested in applying any styling based on data, I am interested solely in geometry of objects.

Comment: There's so many possibilities of how you style the OSM data that I can't see a simple solution...Post your overcomplicated solution *in your question* and point out how its not adequate.

Comment: @Spacedman I updated my question, sorry for not specifying earlier that I am interested solely in geometries. I got so focused on my usecase that I forgot that generating instruction for CNC laser is not a typical use of .svg files :(

Comment: Given that both .osm and .svg are XML dialects I think that means it could be doable with an XSLT - a spec (also in XML) for converting between XMLs. But its not a job I'd like to take on!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/27436/easiest-way-to-render-several-svg-maps-in-mapnik-style you have some choices that work for me:

- Try [Maperitive](http://maperitive.net/)

It lets you download osm data for the current view, and export to SVG for Inkscape or Adobe Illustrator. It uses the OSM styles by default

- Try [Nik2img](https://github.com/springmeyer/nik2img)

It requires the data to be in a postgis database populated with osm2pgsql, and uses OSM stylesheets as well. The command line would be something like

```
nik2img\nik2img.py osm-de.xml out.svg --format svg --srs 900913 --bbox 6.47 51.4 6.48 51.41 --world-file wld
```

Mapnik is also able to consume raw osm data and output SVG, but I have not tested it myself. At lest the demo of Mapnik 2.2.0 has SVG output on a very simple stylesheet (rendering shapefiles).

Comment: I will accept your answer, as while I will use `osmtogeojson` + `mapshaper` script your answer is more likely to be useful for a typical visitor.

Answer (score 3):

Following method is nice for automatic scipts:

Convert `.osm` to GeoJSON (for example using https://github.com/tyrasd/osmtogeojson ) or to obtain it directly in GeoJSON (for example using Overpass Turbo).

Import GeoJSON file to https://mapshaper.org/ and export `.svg` file.

There is also CLI, see https://github.com/mbloch/mapshaper for details. For example

```
osmtogeojson file.osm > file.geojson
mapshaper -i file.geojson -o format=svg
```

will convert file.osm to file.svg

It was partially based on https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/SVG (and I added to this page parts that were missing).

Comment: Osm to geojson should be possible with GDAL too. Do you use the mapshaper command line?

Comment: Couple of things I've realised: Instead of fiddling with osmtogeojson you can actually use JOSM to save as geojson. Not so obvious, but JOSM lets you simply "Save as" and give it a `.geojson` extension! Secondly MapShaper outputs fairly crude SVG with two grouped sets of objects corresponding to the polylines and polygons of a shapefile. The polygons will start out filled in black with no outlines, meaning your map will just look like a black splodge when you first open it in inkscape. Initially I was deleting the black polygons, but realised I wanted do fill:none + outline stroke:black.